# How to convert loop in Python

Tags: python

I have the following code

```
for (int i = 0; 1 < array.length; i++) { 
for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
```

How should I convert it in Python language ?

Comment: what have you tried and what problem with **your** code you have?

Answer (score 1):

That's two nested loops. You can directly translate it into Python, if you want:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(array)):
       ...
```

But iterating over indexes is often unnecessary in Python, unless you need the indexes for some reason *other* than indexing to get the values from the array. If you just want pairs of items, use `itertools.combinations`:

```
for i_item, j_item in itertools.combinations(array, 2):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

That's just two nested for loops, you can do the equivalent in Python like this:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in range(len(array)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(array)):
        #code
```

The outer `for` loop iterates through the array using the range function and the len function to get the length of the array. The inner for loop does the same, but starts at index i+1 and goes up to the end of the array using the same range function.

Another way to do this is to use the built-in `enumerate()` function to get the index and element at the same time, like this:

```
    for i, _ in enumerate(array):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(array)):
            #code
```